# implement restart as Administrator in C# console app

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a console app that deletes some files, and it can only do that if it is started as administrator.

When the app is started not as administrator I would prefer for it to:

1. close
2. and start again,
3. and the user to get the "start as administrator Yes/No dialog box"

(kinda like notepad++ when you try to edit a certain file, it asks you if you want to restart as administrator)

is this something easy to do in C# ?

Comment: *is this something easy to do in C# ?* yes, it is (but in 3, 2 ,1 order) ... what had you tries so far? There are already answers to the question  how to start process from C# with admin rights

Comment: 3, 2, 1 that means that I right click and choose open as administrator, which doesn't involve code. I want the app to close and reopen with the windows dialog box asking if you want to open as administrator

Comment: you start app, apps check if has admin rights if not, it starts itself with admin rights, UAC dialog appear, non admin instance can be closed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to the wise advice in the comments, I managed to get it done.

```
static void Main()
{
    if (!IsAdministrator())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("restarting as admin");
        StartAsAdmin(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        return;
    }
    ...
}

public static bool IsAdministrator()
{
    var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
    return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}

public static void StartAsAdmin(string fileName)
{
    var proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = fileName, 
            UseShellExecute = true, 
            Verb = "runas"
        }
    };

    proc.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this similarly to @buga but wanted the arguments too.

```
public static bool CheckIsAdmin()
{
    using (WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
    {
        var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
        return principal?.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) ?? false;
    }
}

public const string RUNAS = "runas";
public const string CANCEL = "CANCEL";
public const string DOUBLEQUOTE = "\"";
public const string SPACE = " ";


public static bool CheckIsAdminAndElevate(bool quitIfNeedToElevate = true)
{
    if (CheckIsAdmin())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        var commandLineArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        var exePathArg = commandLineArgs?.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
        var otherArgs = commandLineArgs?.Skip(1)?.Select(oA => (oA?.Contains(SPACE) ?? false) ? $"{DOUBLEQUOTE}{oA}{DOUBLEQUOTE}" : oA)?.ToList();
        var otherArgsStr = string.Join(SPACE, otherArgs ?? new List<string>());
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo(exePathArg, otherArgsStr);
        info.UseShellExecute = true;
        info.Verb = RUNAS;
        try
        {
            Process.Start(info);
            if (quitIfNeedToElevate)
            {
                Environment.Exit(exitCode: 0);
            }
        }
        catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception exc)
        {
            // This will presumably be "The operation was canceled by the user"
            // We want to catch/handle user cancellation - but other exceptions should be thrown as normal
            // We might just check the word "cancel" is somewhere in the message to make sure.
            if ((exc?.Message?.IndexOf(CANCEL, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?? -1) < 0)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

For what it's worth the reason I was doing this was to check a service and re-start it as needed. So I wrote a small app that would take a service name as an argument, and if it wasn't running, would prompt to elevate. So here it is if that helps too.

```
/// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">Service not found.</exception>
public static bool IsServiceRunning(string serviceName)
{
    using (var sc = new ServiceController(serviceName))
    {
        return (sc?.Status ?? ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) == ServiceControllerStatus.Running;
    }
}
const int THIRTYTHOUSAND_MS = 30000;

public static bool StartServiceIfNotRunning(string serviceName, int timeoutMS = THIRTYTHOUSAND_MS)
{
    var timeoutTS = new TimeSpan(days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0, milliseconds: timeoutMS);

    if (IsServiceRunning(serviceName))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        using (var sc = new ServiceController(serviceName))
        {
            if (ProgramHelper.CheckIsAdminAndElevate())
            {

                sc.Start();
                sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeoutTS);
                return IsServiceRunning(serviceName);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```